# What are the different types of M.2 Wifi card found on a modern desktop or laptop motherboard?

Tags: wireless-networking, motherboard

I was trying to buy a new LGA1700 motherboard, and found that there were different options:

- some motherboards had '1x M.2 slot with E-key for PCIe WiFi module only'
- some motherboards had the same, but with a wifi card pre-installed, which could be Intel, AMD, etc.
- some motherboards did not have this at all.

The E-key slot is found behind the I/O plat to allow an aerial to be installed to the card.

What are the different options for the M.2 card?

Answer (score 3):

There is a full list of Intel wifi cards here:

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/series/59485/wireless.html

These go back to 2013 including both mini PCIE and M.2 cards.

More recent cards are all M.2.

Recent series include:

1. 3100 series - 2013-2016 launch, all 1x1, dual band (2.4/5.0GHz), 433mbps, and BT 4.0 (3160) or 4.2 (3165 or 3168)
2. 7200 Series - 2013-2014 including the BT 4.0 7260, and BT 4.2 7265, all 2x2, and with single band 300mbps, dual band - 300 or 867mbps variants
3. 8000 series (Bt 4.2)  - 2015-2017 replacing the 7200 series with the 8260 and 8265 both dual band 867mbps models
4. 9000 series (Bt 5.1) - 2017 - replacing the 3100 and 8000 series with 9461 (1x1), and 9462 (1x1 antenna diversity) the 433 mbps models, and the 9260 and 9560 the faster 1.73 mbps 2x2 models
5. Wifi 6 series (BT 5.2) - 2019 - 2.4 Gbps, 2x2 dual band, BT 5.2, AX200 or AX201 models, plus the 'Killer' AX 1650
6. Wifi 6e series (BT 5.2) - 2020- now triple band 5.0 GHz (because '6e'). AX210, AX211, Killer AX1675, AX411 and Killer AX1690 models.

Starting from the 9000 series, Intel introduced CNVi. This meant that most of their wifi cards would not work except with a compatible Intel chipset. Of the 2017- models, all are CNVi except for the 9260, AX200, AX210, and AX1650.

The 'Killer' products are tweaked versions of the Intel card claiming gaming/lower latency.

The AX411 and AX1690 introduce Dual Connect, allowing connections to two different bands to take advantage of latency/speed differences.

Other brands exist, such as Mediatek MT7921K a Wifi 6E card also rebranded AMD RZ608

For users looking to add wifi or replace a faulty card, a slightly older card is a little cheaper than the current generation.

Intel have stated that there are two versions of CNVi (9000 series = Wifi 5), the first version and CNVi2 (Wifi 6/Wifi 6e). The first version is for 8th/9th gen Intel chips on mobile, and 9th gen desktop, and the second version for 10th gen and newer.

In general there are reports that 8th/9th gen laptops supplied with Wifi5 CNVi cards do not work with CNVi2 (Wifi 6) cards. However they are reported in many cases to work fine with the non-CNVi Wifi 6/6e cards: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1086207-upgrading-laptops-with-cnvio-v1-wifi-adapters-eg-wireless-ac-9560-to-wifi-6-intel-ax200210/

According to Intel one must check with the manufacturer: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000038015/wireless.html Therefore if your motherboard or laptop comes supplied with a CNVi card, then it might not work with a non-CNVI card. However if it's sold as 'M.2 type E' without any mention of CNVi, then both types should work.

Note that I found for example the Gigabyte B660 DS3H motherboard has two variants, AC = Intel 3168, and AX = AMD RZ608 (rebranded Mediatek). Other boards may ship with both Intel Wireless 6 and 6E, even with the same model name (distinguished only by version number). As such, the 'value added' by the wifi card being supplied with a motherboard is not constant for a given motherboard generation but must be drilled down to the actual wifi card that you are getting, because paying $30 extra for the 3168 would be a bad deal, but for a AX210, perfectly reasonable.

Also note that some cards mare listed as Bluetooth 5.0 or whatever but in fact support a more recent Bluetooth version - check the driver support on the manufacturer's website.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comprehensive answer! Am I right that a non-CNVi WiFi-6 card (like AX1650) _may work_ for older chipsets (with M.2 type E)? Namely, I have `HP Elitdesk 800 G2 Mini` with `Intel Q170` chipset